# TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm writing a node.js app using express and mongoose-auth. When I run my app, I get a webpage with the following stacktrace.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

    at HTTPServer. (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/mongoose-auth/node_modules/everyauth/lib/expressHelper.js:7:27)
    at ServerResponse._render (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:393:58)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:315:17)
    at /home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/app.js:41:7
    at callbacks (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/home/levi/Projects/Cloudrr/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:201:15)
```

Here's my app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongooseAuth = require('mongoose-auth');
var model = require("./models");
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(mongooseAuth.middleware())
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});
// Database

var Proffile = mongoose.model('Profile', model.Profile);
var Cloudrr = mongoose.model('Cloudrr', model.Cloudrr);
var Cloud  = mongoose.model('Cloud', model.Cloud);
var User = mongoose.model('User', model.UserSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cloudrr');
// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Cloudrr | Lorem ipsum'
  });
});
app.get('/index', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Cloudrr | Lorem ipsum'
  });
});
app.get('/left', function(req, res){
    if(req.loggedIn == True)
    {
        Profile.findById(req.user, function(user){
        res.render('left', {
            title: "Welcome back!",
            user_id: user.profileID,
            avatar: user.avatar,
            followers: user.followers.length(),
            following: user.following.length(),
        });
        });
    }
    else
    {
    res.render("left", {
        title: "you need to log in."
    });
    }
});

mongooseAuth.helpExpress(app);
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

and package.json.

```
{
    "name": "cloudrr"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.4.6"
    , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
    , "mongoose": ">= 2.1.3"
    , "mongoose-types": ">= 1.0.3"
    , "mongoose-auth": ">= 0.0.11"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The stack trace points to line 41, which is in the middle of the first route. A google search shows me a couple issues in the everyauth issue tracker with the same error, but none of the solutions provided work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can track this down yourself by editing the file at the top of the stack 'expressHelper.js' and inserting a 'debugger' statement in the method that's throwing the exception.  Then use the built-in node debugger or a tool like node-inspector (my debugger of choice) to examine the state and callpath to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was unbalanced brackets, so fixing thee bracket balance fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a required step, see Schema Decoration in the [mongoose-auth documentation](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/blob/master/README.md).

You might be where I was a few weeks ago. If your current application is new, and therefore still small, you might want to start a new project using the mongoose-auth example program. After you have verified you can login and logout, you can add your application functionality.